# how to migrate to angular rc6 ngModules

Tags: angularjs

I'm going from RC4 to RC6.  I'm trying to read angluar.io's website, and some of the instructions are not clear for me.

I have a couple of basic questions, that I'm hoping for more clear answers to:

1. If I have 15 components, what tells me that I need to split them among multiple ngModules?
2. in RC4, I have directives, how do I know when to push them into either imports or declarations?

Thanks much

Comment: 1) Modules are hierarchical and any conceivable organization makes sense if it makes sense from a functional perspective.  I have 15 classes...what tells me...?

2) In RC5 the declarations section is for dependent components (or pipes), the imports section is for dependent modules, and then you have providers for (you guessed it) services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to turn each component into it's own module. If two components are closely related I would turn them into a module.

`imports` are used to include other modules in the current module.

`declarations` are used to declare all the components of the module.

Comment: ok.  so for in case of a dashboard, you can put all of the sub-components on the same module, but if you have say a game-page, with a different route, you can make another ngModule, correct?

Comment: @arcee123 Yes, you could do that.

Comment: ok.  this makes more sense.  It appeared like I needed a module per component.  Does that mean all SERVICE PROVIDERS, regardless of component listed, must be listed in the ngModule?

Comment: Providers referenced in any of the components of the module will need to be declared under providers in the module.

Also if you need another module to use this modules component, then it must be added to the 'exports' as well.

Comment: @arcee123 It solely depends on what a component expects. If it needs its own service instance, it should have its own provider. Otherwise a service may be listed in ngModule.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official angular migration from RC4 to RC5 before ;)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html